# Linker error with MathGL in XCode

Tags: c++, xcode, linker, mathgl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

I'm trying to plot some matrices on 3D-graphs using MathGL with XCode. I managed (after a long day of frustration) to cmake, make and install MathGL (even had to install libpng, but that's a differents story). So, I managed to add the MathGL include path (*/usr/local/include*) to the XCode C++ project and it is working, since the autocompletion autocompletes the `mgl2/mgl.h` header file. Yet when I'm trying to build my code, which is only making one `mglGraph` member, I'm getting many linker errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_mgl_create_graph", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_mgl_delete_graph", referenced from:
      mglGraph::~mglGraph() in main.o
  "_mgl_set_font_size", referenced from:
      mglGraph::SetFontSizePT(double, int) in main.o
  "_mgl_use_graph", referenced from:
      mglGraph::~mglGraph() in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
```

I know there are many posts out there (some even from me) listing problems with including correctly etc. but this one I just can't find any help for. So please anybody, how do I get this to work?

I've tried changing/modifying the environment PATH and DYLD_* paths to include the */usr/local/...* paths, but that didn't work. I've tried adding ALL folders in */usr/local/* to the include path. I've tried compiling in 32 and 64 bit. I've tried including the */usr/local/lib* in the library search path. But nothing worked. So please any help is very much appreciated.

Regards
Max

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12574400/673730

Comment: The problem isn't including files, but with linking.

Comment: I figured that... The solution listed is specific MSVS. But I'm using XCode. On the other hand, I tried compiling with g++ in the terminal and added the linker flag (*-l/usr/local/lib*) but that didn't work either :/

Comment: You need to specify which exact library to link against. I don't know the command in XCode, but you can easily find it with google. It might be something like `-l/.../mathgl.lib`...

Comment: Hey, thanks for that :D Didn't try "dragging and dropping" the "dylib" file into the project folder. Is seems one has to: 1. Add the *User Header Search Paths*, 2. add the *Library Search Path* and 3. then *drag and drop* the actual library reference into the project folder. Now it compiles, runs and makes my graph(s) :]

Comment: Regardless of the IDE, it's almost always the same - you have to specify which library to use.

Comment: I added the steps to the answer in the related question and voted to close this. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: Since I got my answer, closing this is probably best ;) Ta

Comment: Hi Max, I'm going through the exact same pain of installing Mathgl on mac and your Q popped up. How did you install libpng, as it is causing me a lot of stress! Cheers Sam

Comment: I've installed Mathgl, but how did you get xcode to find mgl2/mgl.h ?

Comment: @SamPalmer: It's been a while, but I believe I installed libpng like so: First I downloaded it from [here]( http://libpng.sourceforge.net/index.html), then using cmake to make the code, and then `sudo make` & `sudo make install` to install it. It should all automatically install correctly and then just work with MathGL.

Comment: @SamPalmer: Imported (drag-and-drop also works) the libmgl.dlyb into the Project navigator. Then added `/usr/local/include` and `/usr/local/lib` to the **target's** Header Search Paths and Library Search Paths respectively. You know it has worked when trying to write `#include <mgl2/mgl.h>` in your header and the Xcode autocomplete feature shows the mgl2 folder's content as you do so.

Comment: Cheers, great help its auto-completeing so I guess thats a good sign.

Comment: So i've got all the compilation working, did you come across an error that creating the data throws a bad access?